# How to create folds with foldmethod indent in vim?

Tags: vim

I am trying to learn how to use folds in vim. 
Folding manually works great but I would like to know how to fold via indents. I expect it to work like this:

```
+------
   +--- | //Place marker here and press 'zf'
   +---
+------
```

Will result in:

```
+------
<fold>
+------
```

But I just get

`E350: Cannot create fold with current 'foldmethod'`

Any ideas why I get this error?

Also, is there a way to create a fold in between curly braces?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want an automatic fold based on the indentation you need to set the `foldmethod` option to `indent` value

```
:set foldmethod=indent
```

And that's the reason probably why you get that error. I suppose it is set like above.

> **zf{motion}**  or {Visual}zf Operator to create a fold.      **This only works
>   when 'foldmethod' is "manual" or "marker"**.      The new fold will be
>   closed for the "manual" method.

you can check your `foldmethod` to confirm that by `:set foldmethod?`

whenever you are in a range of **lines with the same indentation** you need only to click on <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> so that block will be folded.

If you want to create manually your folds you need to set this time the `foldmethod` to `manual`.

Put your cursor on one of the curly braces and type <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>%</kbd> that will fold all the block between {}

Comment: My foldmethod is set correctly. Sorry, I should have mentioned that in my post. Folding curly braces works exactly how you said! I think I will settle with that method for now.

Comment: I had `foldmethod=syntax`. See [this SE answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/336537/78809) for some useful details.